# Select random elements from the list

Tags: r, list

How can I select random files (`randomFiles`) which would not contain `f`?

```
allFiles = list.files("D:/test")

for(f in allFiles)
{
   randomFiles = sample(allFiles, size = 10)
   #...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
allFiles <- list.files("D:/test")

for( i in seq_along(allFiles) )
{
   randomFiles <- sample(allFiles[-i], size = 10)
   #...
}
```

Or you could also use one of those very useful set functions:

```
for( f in allFiles )
{
  randomFiles <- sample(setdiff(allFiles, f), size = 10)

  #...
}
```